# Ошибка компиляции LNK 2005

Tags: c++

main.cpp

```
#include "server.h"

void main()
{
}
```

packet.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _PACKET_H
#define _PACKET_H

..

#endif
```

server.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _SERVER_H
#define _SERVER_H

#include "packet.h"
..

#endif
```

Список ошибок:

> Ошибка    LNK2005 "public: virtual void __thiscall IncomingAuth::handler(class Parcer &)" (?handler@IncomingAuth@@UAEXAAVParcer@@@Z) уже определен в main.obj EmulatorTop C:\Users\Ilya\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EmulatorTop\ThreadEvents\server.obj

Если изменить main, то компилируется.

main.cpp

```
#include "packet.h"

void main()
{
}
```

Comment: В server.h у вас что-то не только объявлено, но и **определено**, так что в результате при компиляции и server.cpp, и main.cpp вы получаете две сущности с одним и тем же именем, что очень расстраивает компоновщик...

Comment: И еще - это ошибка не КОМПИЛЯЦИИ, а ЛИНКОВКИ.

Comment: Оказывается, в packet.h были определены классы и методы. Вынес методы в .cpp и все заработало.

Comment: Ну, я не удивлен :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор выдает сообщения об ошибках специально для вас, чтобы вы их читали. Данное сообщение об ошибке, выдаваемое при линковке единиц компиляции, очень ясное: функция `handler` определена в двух единицах компиляции.

Скорей всего она определена в заголовочном файле `server.h` и при этом не является встраиваемой, то есть не имеет спецификатора функции `inline`.

Либо уберите определение функции из заголовка, либо объявите ее со спецификатором `inline`.

Имейте в виду, что хотя компилятор MS VC++ компилирует такое объявление функции `main`, как

```
void main()
```

оно не соответствует стандарту C++. Согласно стандарту функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена как

```
int main()
```